# C# WebView2 change user-agent is not working?

Tags: c#, winui-3, webview2

here is my code:

```
 public MainWindow() { 
    this.InitializeComponent(); 
    this.Title = "mainWindow"; 
    Task.Run(async () => { 
        await this.webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(); 
        this.webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.UserAgent = "windows/webview2"; 
    }); 
}
```

but in devtool, the user-agent remains unchanged:

```
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/108.0.1462.54
```

Comment: And where is the code you have shown above? In what event?

Comment: @NineBerry winui3.

Comment: @NineBerry, no event, I just add it in the window constructor function:

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you try to access the WebView from another thread than the main ui thread.

Instead of running the code in a separate thread, execute it in a `CoreWebView2Initialized` event handler:

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Set eventhandler
        webView.CoreWebView2Initialized += WebView_CoreWebView2Initialized;
    }

    private void WebView_CoreWebView2Initialized(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2InitializedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Set custom user agent string in Initialized event
        sender.CoreWebView2.Settings.UserAgent = "Test/Stackoverflow";
    }

    private async void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myButton.Content = "Clicked";
        
        // Browse to website 
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
        webView.Source = new Uri("https://www.browserlookup.com/");
    }
}
```

---

This works for me in most cases. There is still [a known bug in the WebView2](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2862) that means that the custom user agent name is not used when a specific website is visited for the first time. Funnily enough, the only website I could reproduce the bug with is "whatismybrowser.com"...

Comment: is there window `Loaded` event in winui3?, I don't want to `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` in   button click.

Comment: You can use the loaded event of the WebView2 itself.