# How to set custom user agent and browser info in WebView2 in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, user-agent, webview2

I am creating a WPF app which utilizes the WebView2 Component in C#.

At the moment the default info sent by WebView2 to websites, in regards to user agent information  is:

`"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.58"`,

(I used WhatIsMyBrowser.com to find out).

Also, the website recognizes the WebView2 component as "Edge 114 on Windows 10".

How can I customize the information sent? For example, how can I make the Web Browser Recognition sites recognize the WebView2 Component "MyCustomWebBrowser on Windows 10"  and the user agent information as "MyCustomBrowser/1.0 (Windows ....)"

I tried using the [CoreWebView2Settings.UserAgent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings.useragent?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1823.32) Property in my main window code.

```
     public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainWebBrowser.CoreWebView2.Settings.UserAgent = "MyCustomBrowser/1.0 (Windows ....)";
        }
```

but I am getting several errors.

Note that I have named the WebView2 component MainWebBrowser in xaml.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940068/c-sharp-webview2-change-user-agent-is-not-working